Routing in Next.js with locale and a category in the path
I'm trying to build a blog with a specific URL path in mind, specified as follows
...
i18n: {
    // These are all the locales you want to support in
    // your application
    locales: ['en', 'de'],
    // This is the default locale you want to be used when visiting
    // a non-locale prefixed path e.g. `/hello`
    defaultLocale: 'en',

    // localePath: path.resolve('./public/locales')
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        // Assuming 'default.js' should handle the base of each slug
        source: '/:locale/:cat/:slug*',
        destination: '/post/slug/',
      } 
    ];
  }, 
...

My folder structure is:
post -> slug -> default.js
I'm trying to map the URL:
localhost.com/locale/category/slug
for example
localhost.com/en/beaches/best-beaches
But it doesn't fig the path it always gives me a 404, any suggestion how to achieve this ?
